# Question about c++ lambda (with non-automatic storage duration)

Tags: c++, lambda, storage, duration

My code is as the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int x;

struct A
{
    auto func()
    {
        auto test([&, &x](){cout << x << endl;});
        test();
    }
};

int main()
{
   A a;
   x = 5;
   a.func();
}
```

My program is as the above, I compiled it with the following command

```
g++ -std=c++11 ex.cpp -o ex
```

However, I get a warning as the following

> ex.cpp: In member function ‘auto A::func()’:
>   ex.cpp:11:19: warning: capture of variable ‘x’ with non-automatic storage duration
>   `auto test([&, &x](){cout << x << endl;});`
>   `^`
>   ex.cpp:6:5: note: ‘int x’ declared here
>   `int x;`

Can anybody help me resolve it?

Comment: `x` is a global variable, no need to capture it.

Comment: And the "capture all" is also unneeded. you capture nothing actually.

Answer (score 4):

Your lambda actually doesn't capture anything:

`x` is a global variable (as `std::cout`).

Simply remove capture:

```
auto func()
{
    auto test([](){ std::cout << x << std::endl; });
    test();
}
```